# find indices of group of equal values python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a 1D array containing -1,0,1

```
Mask
Out[6]: array([0, 0, 0, -1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1])
```

I would like to find the start and the end indices of groups of equal values.
This can be stored in a dataframe in which the first column is the start index, the second column the end index, and the tirdh column the value that is repeated.

```
start end value
0,    2,  0
3,    4,  -1
5,    6,  0
7,    8,  1
```

Is there a way to do this or I have to use a  loop over the `Mask`?
Hereby my attempt

```
Change =pd.DataFrame(columns=['Start','End','Value'])

i=-1
while i <len(Mask)-1:
    i = i + 1
    start = i
    end = i
    value = Mask[start]
    if i <len(Mask)-1:
       while Mask[i]==Mask[i+1]:
          i = i +1
          end = i
          if i >=len(Mask)-1:
              end = i + 1 
              break

    detected = []
    detected .append([start,end,value])
    detected = np.array(detected )
    detected = pd.DataFrame(detected , columns=['Start','End','Value'])    
    Change = pd.concat([Change , detected ], ignore_index=True)[Change .columns.tolist()]
```

Comment: so the question is whether you can do it *without* a `for` loop?

Comment: yes, basically I had in mind to check for the next value within a for loop etc... but I think there is a pythonic way to do so

Comment: I understand that list comprehensions look cooler but I see nothing wrong with a `for` loop. Another thing you can take a look at is `groupby` (https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

Comment: I posted my solution with 2 while loops in the edited question... I think it is not the most elegant... could you please have a look at it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Data:**

```
In [178]: s = pd.Series([0, 0, 0, -1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1])

In [179]: s
Out[179]:
0    0
1    0
2    0
3   -1
4   -1
5    0
6    0
7    1
8    1
dtype: int64
```

**Solution:**

```
In [180]: r = (s.reset_index(name='val')
     ...:       .groupby(s.diff().ne(0).cumsum())
     ...:       .agg({'val':{'value':'first'}, 'index':{'start':'min','end':'max'}})
     ...: )
     ...:

In [182]: r.columns = r.columns.droplevel(0)
```

**Result:**

```
In [183]: r
Out[183]:
   value  start  end
1      0      0    2
2     -1      3    4
3      0      5    6
4      1      7    8
```

**UPDATE:** workaround for `FutureWarning: using a dict with renaming is deprecated and will be removed in a future version`

```
In [47]: r = s.reset_index(name='val').groupby(s.diff().ne(0).cumsum()).agg({'val':'first', 'index':['min','max']})

In [48]: r.columns = r.columns.droplevel(0)

In [49]: r = r.rename(columns={'first':'value','min':'start','max':'end'})

In [50]: r
Out[50]:
   start  end  value
1      0    2      0
2      3    4     -1
3      5    6      0
4      7    8      1
```

Comment: Hi @MaxU, this gives me a warning....C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py:3961: FutureWarning: using a dict with renaming is deprecated and will be removed in a future version
  return super(DataFrameGroupBy, self).aggregate(arg, *args, **kwargs)

Comment: @gabboshow, yeah, the API has been changed in Pandas 0.20.0 so using dict of dicts in `.agg()` will be deprecated. I've updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `diff` method in a `Series` on the `Mask` array (after converting it to a `Series`):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


Mask = np.array([0, 0, 0, -1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1])
Mask = pd.Series(Mask)
starts = Mask[~Mask.diff().eq(0)].index.values
ends = Mask[Mask.diff().eq(0)].index[1:].values
vals = Mask[~Mask.diff().eq(0)].values

Change = pd.DataFrame({'start':starts, 'end':ends, 'value':vals})
```

Change should be something like:

```
   end  start  value
0    2      0      0
1    4      3     -1
2    6      5      0
3    8      7      1
```

I hope this proves useful.

Comment: Hi @Abdou, this method does not work if Mask is pd.Series(np.array([0, 0, 0, -1, -1, 0, 0, 1]))